# Error declaring constant in react ts component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have tried to convert a search bar css control I found online which was written in React JS, to React TS but am sort of new to TS and struggling to know what to search for and find out what is wrong with the last problem line.

The error is on the `const { inputValue } = this.state;` line and the message is

> Type 'Readonly<{}>' has no property 'inputValue' and no string index
>   signature.

My control code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class ControlBar extends React.Component {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          inputValue: ''
        };

        this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
      }

    onInputChange(e: any) {
        const { value } = e.target;

        this.setState({
          inputValue: value
        });
      }

    public render() {
         const { inputValue } = this.state;

        return (<div className='input-wrapper'>
            <input
              placeholder='Search...'
              value={inputValue}
              spellCheck={false}
              />
            <span className='input-highlight'>
            { inputValue.replace(/ /g, "\u00a0") }
          </span>  
          </div>);


  }
}

export default ControlBar;
```

Comment: public render ? please remove public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the type of the state in the `S` part of the signature of `React.Component`:

```
React.Component<P,S>
```

Define an interface for it:

```
interface ControlBarState {
    inputValue?: string
}
```

Then declare your class as:

```
class ControlBar extends React.Component<YourPropsType, ControlBarState>
```